# Travel from Mexico to Europe being unemployed

Tags: europe, mexican-citizens

I'm planning a 2 week trip to Europe (Spain, England, Scotland, Belgium and Germany) in the middle of June. I am currently working as software developer but my contract ends on June, one day before the trip, I'm planning to not renew my contract with my current employer because a I want a better paying job and I'm not longer comfortable there.

I'm 25 years old and financially I have the savings to make the 2 week trip. As the journey date gets closer I'll be in active search for a new job on Mexico.

Besides I won't be travelling alone, I'll be traveling with my girlfriend who is currently studying in Spain, she is also mexican and she returns on July 5th to Mexico, she also has enough money saved for the trip.

I already bought the tickets for every flight inside Europe and my return to Mexico. so...

**In short,** when I make the trip I'll be unemployed but in active job search, will this affect my chances to enter any of this countries? and How should I handle the situation when passing Immigration at the airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mexican nationals are visa-free for both the Schengen area and the United Kingdom.

This means that the border authorities will *generally* not be interested in digging into a Mexican tourist's precise ties to his home country; if they wanted to do that for all or most Mexicans, there would be a visa requirement instead.

Thus, you can expect the border guards you meet will be mostly interested in *your visit*. If you fit the profile of a bona fide tourist (that is, you have concrete and definite plans, hotel and flight bookings, have a reasonable amount of money for your trip, and can answer questions about all this coherently and confidently) then it is unlikely that you will be asked very piercing questions about your domestic situation.

You will likely be asked a few basic questions such as what is your profession -- and then you can truthfully answer that you're a software developer. Unless they ask explicitly about your current employment you don't need to volunteer that information -- but if they do ask, that's not the end of the world, just plainly say something like "I'm between jobs, and am currently seeking opportunities *back in Mexico*." Don't forget the three last words!

Be sure **NOT** to travel with documents such as hardcopy CVs, portfolios, university diplomas or the like, which could give an immigration officer rummaging through your bags the impression that you're going to apply for jobs in Europe. (For a *visa application* some of these documents might help substantiate that you have a rational expectation of finding well-paid work in Mexico soon, but bringing them with you to the border is a different matter and can only backfire!)